# Не получается в GitHub соединить с терминалом VS Code через команду git checkout gh-pages Хочу локально создать Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: git, git-checkout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image]

Мне нужно настроить git чтобы он работал с VS code editor
При настройке через терминал
Не вышло [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по приведённой картинке, у вас всё получилось. если вы считаете, что не получилось, приведите, пожалуйста, свои соображения непосредственно в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: сделайте git init в нужном вам репозитории

Comment: Александр, не вышло Я не знаю в чем проблема 
нужно ветку git checkout gh-pages соединить с vs code editor 
git clone загружает копирует все Но сам файл не могу соединить Файл называется Coursera-test .  Команда ls не работает в терминале все делаю как по видио но где то явно мелкая ошибка Есть возможность помочь? 
https://www.coursera.org/learn/html-css-javascript-for-web-developers/lecture/4T1t0/development-environment-setup-part-3-github-and-browser-sync

Comment: в вашем сообщении намешано несколько абсолютно разных понятий, что говорит о том, что вы не совсем понимаете что делаете. Распишите по пунктам чего вы хотите добиться

Comment: 1 Открываю терминал
2 git clone https://github.com/Pavel-vovk90/coursera-test.git
3 ls   и тут не работает команда эта а должно появиться coursera-test
4 cd coursera-test/
5 ls и снова не работает а должно быть README.md
6 git status
7 git checkout gh-pages
8 git status
9 ls должно выйти index.htmlbbbbparams.json    styleesheets  не работает
10 mkdir   site

Comment: 1 Открываю терминал
2 git clone https://github.com/Pavel-vovk90/coursera-test.git
3 ls   и тут не работает команда эта а должно появиться coursera-test
4 cd coursera-test/
5 ls и снова не работает а должно быть README.md
6 git status
7 git checkout gh-pages
8 git status
9 ls должно выйти index.htmlbbbbparams.json    styleesheets  не работает
10 mkdir   site
11 cd   site 
12 ls
Помогите пожалкйста мне нужно  файлы из git hub перенести в vs code через терминал

Answer (score 0):

Консоль, через которую вы должны выполнять команды не `CMD` от  `Windows`, а `Git Bash`, его необходимо устанавливать отдельно. Обратите внимание, на второй фотографии команды выполняются в терминале `Bash` (в заголовке окна название)